# Функция подстановки чисел

Tags: php

Сама суть:

Нужно вывести 12 символов, причем а такой последовательности:

например если 4 цифры, 1111,   нужно вывести  в таком формате 000000111100

если три, например 222,   то: 000000022200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo rep("1111") . "\n";
echo rep("222") . "\n";

function rep ($str){
    $res = "000000000000";
    if(strlen($str) > 10 ){
        return false;
    } else{
        return preg_replace('#.{'. strlen($str). '}(?=00$)#', $str, $res);
    }
}
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3cS3XN)

Answer (score 0):

т.е. вы считаете, что

```
$val = 23;
printf("%'010s",$val);
```

Не так круто как циклы создавать?

Comment: Не настолько круто, ибо это вообще возвращает не то что ожидалось.

зы: т.е вы считаете, что не дочитывать вопрос не так круто чем сразу давать ответ ? :)

Comment: а в чем проблема два нуля вывести после в формате строки? Я же мог вообще ответить, что пользуйтесь функциями форматированного вывода строк. Но даже пример написал.